# How to reverse engineer str_shuffle (PHP) to get its mt_rand outputs

Tags: cryptography, php, random

```
$output = str_shuffle("12345");
```

E.g. `$output` is now `25134`
How do I find out what numbers came out of `mt_rand()` to allow for the shuffle 
I want to know this because I want the seed of `mt_rand()` and `str_shuffle()` uses `mt_rand()` which is not cryptographically secure as it uses [Mersenne Twister (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) I know shuffle for python is using the [Fisher Yates shuffle (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)
but I have no idea how it works in php. you can get the seed used if you have 624 outputs using [mersenne-twister-recover (GitHub)](https://github.com/eboda/mersenne-twister-recover) or you can brute force the seed with [untwister (GitHub)](https://github.com/altf4/untwister)

Comment: So the question actually is *"how can I know the seed of `mt_rand()` after I've called it for the 1st time"*?

Comment: No str_shuffle probably uses mt_rand() a couple times and its not going to be the only outputs from mt_rand() anyway that I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PHP 7.2.7 sources](https://secure.php.net/get/php-7.2.7.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror), the `str_shuffle` function uses `php_string_shuffle` which does

```
while (--n_left) {
    rnd_idx = php_rand();
    RAND_RANGE(rnd_idx, 0, n_left, PHP_RAND_MAX);
    if (rnd_idx != n_left) {
        temp = str[n_left];
        str[n_left] = str[rnd_idx];
        str[rnd_idx] = temp;
    }
}
```

So I guess you would like to know the intermediate values of `rnd_idx` (since `php_rand()` is an alias of `php_mt_rand()`).

But `RAND_RANGE` is a macro defined as `#define RAND_RANGE(__n, __min, __max, __tmax) (__n) = php_mt_rand_range((__min), (__max))` so the 1st value of the `php_rand()` is already instantly lost.

Hence, you won't get the list of all intermediate `mt_range()` values.

Still, knowing that the algorithm there seems to be `at each round, swap the current letter with a random letter before in the input string; the 1st round takes the last letter as the current one; the next round takes the letter previous current letter as the new current letter` then you can get the `mt_rand` value by reasoning backward.

If `ABCD` is the input value and `BADC` is the result, then it means the values were `2;2;0` (`ABCD` => `ABDC` => `ABDC` => `BADC`) but you still don't know the value of the "lost" calls to `php_mt_rand`. So the sequence of `mt_rand` was actually `?;2;?;2;?;0` which matches the seed `4` and `25`: if you do `mt_srand(4); echo str_shuffle('ABCD');` then you'll get `BADC` and same if your seed is set to `25`. You would need a pretty long chain of unique characters to get a sequence long enough to match only one seed.

Comment: Could you edit it to add an example in python as thats the full question then its still useful as brute forcing the seed is still possible

Comment: It's not a programmer exchange website, such request would more fit stackoverflow. From a cryptographic point of view, the interesting thing is the concept and general process, not the implementation details.

Comment: Okay I will edit my question